# ¿Cómo puedo introducir la entrada de datos de la función input() en la ejecución del programa a medias del texto?

Tags: python, input

me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer esto en Python:

```
peso = float(input("Tamaño: [dato] centímetros"))
```

Es decir, al ejecutar el programa, no sé cómo puedo poner el dato que he tecleado en la ejecución del programa entre medias de dos strings.

Muchas gracias

Comment: `peso = float(input(f"Tamaño: {dato} centímetros"))`

Comment: Perdona, pero es que no me sale.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando yo inserte en la ejecución del programa el dato de 'peso', esté en medio de los dos strings:

Comment: peso = float(input("Peso:  'número'    kilogramos"))

Comment: Y entonces al ejecutar el programa por ejemplo te ponga: Peso: 2 kilogramos

Comment: Tú con el input(), has puesto el valor (2) entre los dos strings al ejecutar el programa

Comment: Me gustaría saber qué código poner para que yo pueda poner ese valor entre los dos strings al ejecutar el programa

Answer (score 0):

La secuencia de escape `\b` mueve el cursor una posición hacia atrás en la consola.
Lo que haremos será imprimir la cadena necesaria y después movernos hacia la posición donde quieres que el usuario escriba el valor que le estás pidiendo.
Por ejemplo:

```
peso = float(input(f"Tamaño:    centímetros\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"))
```

En mi opinión este código es feo e ilegible.
Podemos hacer algo más bonito con una pequeña función:

```py
def input_interpolado(mensage_inicial: str, maximo_input: int, mensage_final: str) -> str:
    # Componemos la string que imprimiremos en consola
    input_str = mensage_inicial
    # Dejamos un hueco para poder escribir lo que necesita el usuario
    input_str += " " * maximo_input
    input_str += mensage_final
    # Retrocedo el cursor hasta donde puede empezar a escribir el usuario
    input_str += "\b" * (len(mensage_final) + maximo_input)

    return input(input_str)
```

Podemos usarla simplemente así, dejando 3 dígitos para escribir la altura.
Fíjate en que añadimos espacios al rodeando el espacio reservado para que escriba el usuario.
Están ahí por un motivo puramente estético.

```py
altura = float(input_interpolado("Tamaño: ", 3, " centímetros"))
```