# Cambiar posicion del cursos en un input

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, vscode, input, cursor

Quisiera consultar ¿De qué forma puedo lograr cambiar la posición del cursor en donde queda a la hora de ejecución de un input? Muestro imágenes para ser más coherente:

[image: Imagen parte del codigo]

Aquí mi objetivo es que se muestre en pantalla dicho mensaje, pero el cursor donde el usuario escriba quede luego de "entero:" y antes del paréntesis descriptivo. Dado que sino queda como el siguiente console.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antes que nada, el código en tu pregunta debe ir como texto y no en imagen, ya que no todos podemos ver imagenes. En cuanto a tu duda, ese tipo de configuraciones personalizadas para el cursor sólo la las consigues usando librerías de terceros, a menos que decidas programar tal funcionalidad por ti mismo, lo cual puede ser un ejercicio bastante instructivo. No lo haremos por ti, debes intentarlo por tu cuenta o tomar el camino fácil y usar una librería ya existente. Saludos

Comment: De todas formas, revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python/27612978#27612978) del sitio en inglés, que tal vez te ayude en lo que intentas hacer. Saludos

Comment: Si estás haciendo una tarea, dudo que te pidan que muevas el cursor del input, ya que no hay una forma facil de hacerlo, sobre todo para alguien que está aun aprendiendo a programar. Si es una tarea, tenlo en cuenta.

Comment: ¿Contesta esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo introducir la entrada de datos de la función `input()` en la ejecución del programa a medias del texto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543014/)