# ¿Cómo formatear una salida por pantalla para capturar un dato por consola en Python?

Tags: python, print

Agradezco de antemano por tomarse el tiempo del leer y orientarme. Desde hace una semana, estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python.
Actualmente, intento trabajar en un conversor de unidades muy elemental, pero como no conozco lo suficiente para diseñar una interfaz gráfica.
He decidido utilizar por el momento caracteres ascii con la función `print()`.
Mi inquietud es la siguiente, ¿cómo puedo formatear la salida del texto, para que el cursor se ubique justo en la posición reservada en la última línea cuando el usuario digita el dato que se solicita?
Lo que pretendo es hacer una especie de textbox rudimentario como los que se usaban en los viejos formularios o programas contables como CG1. Sé que no es la manera y todo eso, pero por el momento sería suficiente mientras consigo avanzar hasta conceptos más complejos como el manejo de las librerías para trabajar en modo gráfico.

ESPECIFICACIONES EQUIPO:
S.O: WIN11 22H2
PROCESADOR: RYZEN 5
RAM: 8GB

Gracias por tu ayuda. Un saludo

CÓDIGO:

```py
print("╔═════════════════════════════╗")
print("║    CONVERSOR DE UNIDADES    ║")
print("╠═════════════════════════════╣")
print("║  [A] TIEMPO   [S-M-H]       ║")
print("║  [B] MASA     [GR-KG-T]     ║")
print("║  [C] LONGITUD [CM-M-KM]     ║")
print("║  [D] DATOS    [B-MB-KB-GB]  ║")
print("╚═════════════════════════════╝")

opc=input("    DIGITE OPCIÓN... [    ]")
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que preguntas depende del tipo de terminal que usas y del sistema operativo, ya que, hasta donde sé, no hay forma de hacerlo para todas las plataformas y hay algunas en las que de plano no se puede. Sugiero que incluyas esta información en la pregunta al [edit]. Un saludo.

Comment: No hay una forma builtin en Python, input es muy simple y, personalmente, sospecho que fue diseñado para hacer debug o programas simples. Tendrás que recurrir a una librería externa. Blessed es muy buena, y te podría servir de paso para solucionar dudas futuras (ejemplo: python no tiene forma de limpiar la pantalla, se suelen usar comandos del sistema para eso)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo introducir la entrada de datos de la función input() en la ejecución del programa a medias del texto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta respuesta funciona en terminales que soportan secuencias de escape ANSI.

La consola de Windows 10 (actualizado) y 11 las soporta pero por defecto están desactivadas, leer más adelante la *solución* para poder utilizarlas.

#### Cambiar el cursor con una secuencia de escape ANSI

Con secuencias de escape ANSI puedes *guardar* la posición del cursor *imprimiendo* la secuencia `\033[s` y luego mover el cursor de regreso a la última posición guardada con `\033[u`.

Tu llamada a `input` luciría algo como:

```
opc=input("    Digite Opción... [\033[s    ]\033[u")
```

Debes tener en cuenta que esto es puramente visual. Nada impide que el usuario escriba *después* del corchete. La limitación principal aquí es que *input* no soporta una longitud y desconoce la *construcción* visual que has hecho y, de hecho, no conoce nada sobre la terminal, simplemente lee de la entrada estándar  que es un *buffer* de líneas.

En otras palabras, `input` no retorna nada hasta que una línea completa se ingresa; hasta entonces, simplemente espera a que la terminal le envíe *algo*.

Hay bibliotecas como [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), que proveen un manejo más exacto y dejan de responder al teclado si tratas de escribir más allá del `]` del *prompt*.

El uso de bibliotecas en general y de esta en particular queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

#### Habilitar secuencias de escape en Windows 10 y 11

Se puede activar ANSI en conhost a través de editar el registro. Bajo `HKCU\Console` debes crear un valor `DWORD` llamado `VirtualTerminalLevel` y establecerlo a 0x1. Debes iniciar `cmd.exe` después de haber hecho el cambio.

Puedes probarlo con el siguiente powershell:

```
"?[1;31mele ?[32mct ?[33mroni ?[35mX ?[36mtar ?[m".Replace('?', [char]27);
```

Si usas Windows 10, debe estar actualizado, pues las primeras versiones no lo soportaban.

**Advertencia**: Editar el registro puede dejar tu sistema inutilizable. Hazlo con cuidado y bajo tu propio riesgo.

Con información de estas respuestas (en inglés) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/255257) y [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663935/255257) y [este comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences-in-c#comment92954461_16799175) en la segunda respuesta.